# UML association current state

Tags: uml, associations

I have two classes and I want to model the state of the link that the association represents. For instance, I want to capture in the model when the link was established (with a timestamp). Is it an association class the best way?

Comment: You probably need to explain what you mean by "state of the link". An association is nothing physical. It just tells that two classes are related somehow.

Comment: Of course, Associations are a static concept, but a link is the instance of an Association. So I want to capture the state of the link, when the two instance of the class that it connects are created.

Comment: Well, the instance of an association is also nothing physical, I'd say. An object uses up memory. The link could at best be the pointer being used. But that does not have a state. It's there and points to some instance or it's there and points to nothing.

Comment: Ok.  But if a use an association class, with a timestamp attribute (creation date for example), would it be a good solution to capture 'when' the link was established?

Comment: Yes, I think an association class is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Association**

You are using that term with a different meaning than UML. In UML an association is a relation between two classes where at least one can access the other. What you are looking for is a time record to capture some state between two classes.

**Relating classes**

Given your narrative it's not possible to come up with a definitive answer. If you have just a relation or not and you want to capture the time then you could simply add some `relationDate` attribute to one of the classes. You just place the time inside when the both classes get linked.

In case you need some history, you would model an association class between both. That would hold the time when the link was established. Again, your narrative is too short to be complete here. What about dropping the link? Shall the drop time be recorded, or shall the element in the association class be deleted?

...